# Smooth color changing when sliding

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm using `SlidingUpPanelLayout` and I want to change layout color from white to `#4096c3` with this code when `SlidingUpPanelLayout` sliding up (float slideOffset is between 0.0-1.0):

```
    SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener onslide = new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
        backcolor = android.graphics.Color.argb(Math.round(255 * slideOffset), 64, 150, 195);
        panel_layout.setBackgroundColor(backcolor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) {

    }
};
```

What is wrong with this code because when I am sliding suddenly it changes from white to `#4096c3`?

Answer (score 1):

your `LinearLayout(Header)` reference:-

```
LinearLayout mTitleLinearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llyout_header);
```

your `SlidingUpPanelLayout` reference:-

```
SlidingUpPanelLayout mLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
```

your listener:-

```
mLayout.addPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);

            //Here is the code which change titleBar color gradually
           mTitleLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor((int) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(slideOffset, Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"), Color.parseColor("#F44336")));


        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, PanelState previousState, PanelState newState) {



        }

        // During the transition of expand and collapse onPanelSlide function will be called.

    });
```